# Calling a click() event on a div in an inactive tab using the Firefox sdk

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to write a Firefox Addon using the Firefox SDK. I want to call click() on a div in an inactive tab when a user clicks on a button in my Addon panel. I already have the tab variable but now I'm just not sure if it's possible to simulate a click on this tab which is not the active tab.

For example, when the tab is active, I go into the console and type:

`$("#div_id").click()`

How can I call such a function when that tab isn't currently active?

My code in my main.js function:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var self = require("sdk/self");

var control_tab = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  width: 212,
  height: 200,
  contentURL: data.url("control-tab.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("get-buttons.js")
});


require("sdk/widget").Widget({
  label: "Control Tab",
  id: "control-tab",
  contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
  panel: control_tab
});

control_tab.port.on("bind_now", function onBind() {
  var bound_Tab = tabs.activeTab;
});

control_tab.port.on("next", function onNext() {
//enter click() event here on bound_Tab
});
```

Comment: I think I need more info - is it a specific tab? If so you could keep a reference to that tab when it is created and attach a content script to it that runs your code. This *should* work assuming that the tab is actually loaded and the content script has actually been attached.

Comment: Yes, sorry, let me clarify. I want to open a tab and go to a website. From there I will click the "bind now" button on my addon which will bind the variable bound_Tab to the tab that is currently active. Now I want to go to another tab, then in my addon click on the "next" button which is supposed to call ('#div_id').click() on the bound_Tab that is now not the active tab. I guess what I'm wondering is how to get the '#div_id' object from that tab which I saved. (assuming that the bound tab has a div called 'div_id')

Comment: Thank your your help @canuckistani. I got it to work after your advice. I attached a content script which finds the div_id and calls click() on it from my main.js file. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Assume you have

```
<input type=hidden id=someID value=true name=someName/>
```

Then:

```
$("#b1").bind("click", function(){

$("#someId").attr("value", "false");

});
```

Then:

Call document.getElementById() and get this element .And call its functions

Comment: I don't think this relates to the Firefox Addon SDK but I am a beginner at it so I'm not sure. I'm editing my question to show the code I have.